# Gallery Image pick intent return null on android 11 and above

Tags: android, kotlin, image-gallery

I'm getting intent data null when trying to pick image from gallery.
What changes shall I make so the code work correctly.

My pick image code is as following:

`

```kotlin
fun pickimage(requestCode: Int){
 val pickIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
    pickIntent.type = "image/*"

    try {
        startActivityForResult(pickIntent,requestCode)
    }
    catch (e:Exception){
        Toast.makeText(requireContext(),requireContext().resources.getString(R.string.error) ,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

`onActivityResult()`

```kotlin
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_GET && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            data?.data?.let { fullPhotoUri ->
                fullPhotoUri.toBytes(viewModel.contentResolver)?.takeIf { it.isNotEmpty() }?.also {
                    file.loadByteArray(it)


                    viewModel.onImageSelected { file }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

permissions

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: did you add android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
to your manifest?

Comment: Yes. I have added that in manifest